# Redirect a 404 to search for the term but keep the 404 status code before the redirect

Tags: 404-error

I am trying to setup WordPress to do an automatic search when there is a 404. Attempting to provide pertinent content that may have been missed.

However, I would also like to trigger the 404 code before redirecting.

I am able to use wp_redirect(), but that forces a redirection code. Can't use 404.

```
function custom_404_redirect() {
    if( is_404() ) {

        $search_term = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1);
        $search_term = str_replace('/','+',$search_term);
        $search_term = str_replace('-','+',$search_term);
        
        status_header( 404 );
        nocache_headers();
        wp_redirect(
            add_query_arg(
                array('s' => $search_term),
                home_url()
            )
        );
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_404_redirect' );
```

I can force a 404, but only to the search results... Not sure how to do the opposite. So the error page has the 404 code and then the redirected search page gets the 302. Or am I overlooking something basic.

```
function wpd_search_template( $template ) {
    status_header( 404 );
}
add_filter( 'search_template', 'wpd_search_template' );
```